# How to make df.to_csv(filename) trigger a pop up?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a dashboard with [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) and I'm trying to allow users of the dashboard to select some data from a table and then download the selected data. It all works fine, there is only one problem: there is no visual confirmation that the selected data has indeed been downloaded!

Consider the following lines of code:

```
df = df.loc[selected_rows]
df.to_csv(filename)
```

**Question:** It works fine in the sense that the df is downloaded and name `filename`. There is however no visible pop up that you usually have when you download a file. How can I make sure that the downloading is confirmed by the visible appearance in the Download section?